# print values of a specific key from a json file using a command line in terminal

Tags: linux, sed, grep

How do you print recursively the values of the `ts` key of all the entries in my json file using `sed` or `jq`.
One entry example:

```
jsondata = {"text":"/home/ubuntu/processed/00","meta":{"file":"/home/ubuntu/processed/00.03.2019/frames/BR_3.23.1_input_1_A/BR_3.23.1_input_1_A_s0_f004080.jpg","path":"/home/ubuntu/processed/00.03.2019/frames/BR_3.23.1_input_1_A/BR_3.23.1_input_1_A_s0_f004080.jpg"},"options":[{"id":1,"text":"Yes"},{"id":2,"text":"No"}],"_input_hash":-1054720619,"_task_hash":-622956281,"_session_id":"GN","_view_id":"blocks","width":1920,"height":1088,"spans":[{"id":"f19c5f90-b4ea-402b-b350-eb4a177a01d7","label":"person","color":"yellow","x":910.3,"y":213.8,"height":644.8,"width":252,"center":[1036.3,536.2],"type":"rect","points":[[910.3,213.8],[910.3,858.6],[1162.3,858.6],[1162.3,213.8]]}],"answer":"accept","ts":"2021-02-09-15"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to print the value associated with the key, not the key itself.

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you can specify `.ts` to select the timestamp of the toplevel object. The `-r` option prints the "raw" value, i.e. without double quotes:

```
jq -r '.ts' file.json
```